# Implementar corretamente o mvc no php

Tags: php, mvc

Galera estou iniciando agora no php, já mexi bastante no java anteriormente porém com php estou tendo algumas dúvidas

Esse é o meu formulário.

```
  <form name="sentMessage" action="controller">
                    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cpf" placeholder="CPF *" id="CPF" required data-validation-required-message="Favor informe o seu CPF.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" placeholder="Sua senha *" id="senha" required data-validation-required-message="Favor informe sua senha">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Entrar">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Queria saber qual a forma correta de passar os dados do formulário para dentro da controladora, sei que em java eu criaria uma classe definia que a action acionaria essa classe e no método doPost pegaria as informações do formulário e faria as devidas validações e redirecionaria para a próxima página. Agora resta a dúvida em PHP.
Alguém poderia mostra um exemplo da forma correta de fazer isso?
Grato